# UnicodeDecodeError when trying to install cassandra ccm

Tags: linux, cassandra, pip, ccm

I tried to install `Cassandra ccm` on `Linux` (`Arch Linux 2015.02`), using `pip install ccm`, but got the following errors:

```
Collecting ccm
Using cached ccm-2.1.11.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-0k62pp2z/ccm/setup.py", line 21, in <module>
    long_description=open(abspath(join(dirname(__file__), 'README.md'))).read(),
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 3897: ordinal not in range(128)

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-0k62pp2z/ccm/
```

How to resolve this issue?

UPDATE

As `ziky`'s comment pointed out, one can install `ccm` using `pip2`.

Comment: it seems that ccm is tested only for python2.7 and 3.4, you're using 3.5; have you tried to install it with these two versions?

Comment: @ziky Arch installed `python 2.7` in `/usr/bin/python2`, and `python 3.5` in `/usr/bin/python`. So how to install `ccm` using `python 2.7` instead of 3.5

Comment: I'm not familiar with arch linx but there should be something like ``pip2`` and ``pip3``, likely ``pip`` is only link to ``pip3``.

Comment: @ziky you are right, I have installed `ccm` using `pip2` successfully.